# Is there a way to distinguish breaches before opening them?

Tags: path-of-exile

Since breaches will be part of the main game starting from 3.0, and since they have been around since a while, I guess that there might be other people wondering about this and/or people that know the answer.

I have played this latest league, but I have not noticed anything special about the hand that highlights the location of a breach. Is there anything that identifies which breach will there be once I open it?

Comment: Afair: no. The only chance to know the Breach prior opening it is to have an affix which sets the Breach type like "Map contains a Chaos Breach".